# add files to a specafic directory inside zip file

Tags: linux, unix, zip

Let's say we have a zip file contains a directory named `aq` and in the current working directory we have files:

```
./
|- aq/a.txt
|- b.txt
```

When i use this command: 
`zip test.zip aq/*` the `a.txt` file will be zipped into the `aq` directory that's inside the zip file

The question is how then can I add `b.txt` into the `aq` directory that's inside the `test.zip` file without putting the `b.txt` in the `aq` directory first which is in the current working directory like what I did with the `a.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

Make a temp directory called, e.g. `/tmp/$$/aq/`, symlink into the temp directory and then do:

```
(cd /tmp/$$ && zip -r $ZIPDEST aq/)
```

i.e. zip using the temp dir. zip by default follows symbolic links, so it puts the file into the zip without making a copy.

This is pretty much how I construct complicated hierarchical zip files without copying everything to make the archive.

Tar has better options for renaming items as you're putting them into the archive, but you asked about zip.